# Mismatch between installed java version and version shown in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

I have installed java 8 on my Ubuntu 14.04 and eclipse 3.8. When I check java and javac versions It shows me 1.8.0_91. But in my eclipse I can only see runtime library JAVASE-1.7. I can see any JAVASE- 1.8 library. What is wrong with my configurations ??

Comment: Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add - and use the appropriate JVM path (I'm currently using `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`). Also, eclipse 3.8 is a little long in the tooth.

Comment: I removed Eclipse indigo and installed eclipse mars 2.0 to avoid hassle. It  shows JAVASE- 1.8 library and works fine. May be indigo not supported for JAVASE- 1.8  ?

Answer (score 1):

When Eclipse Indigo was released in 2011, Java 8 didn't yet exist. At least Luna (2014) is needed to work with Java 8. Currently (May 2016) Mars.2 is recommended.